# Не работает jquery загрузка файлов

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, form

Итак, подгружаю jquery, подгружаю jquery.form с официального ресурса.  
**console.log($)** перед началом "проблемного" момента выводит следующий результат:

```
function (a,b){return new m.fn.init(a,b)}
```

То есть ничего особенного. Также есть функция загрузки файлов и, как правило, форма загрузки:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {  
    console.log($);  
    $("#avatar").live("change", function()  
    {  
        $("#preAva").html(''); // чистим preview  
        $("#preAva").html('<img src="images/load.gif" height="32" />');  
        $("#formAvaUpload").ajaxForm(  
        {  
            target: '#preAva'  
        }).submit();  
    });  
});
```

Но когда я перезагружаю страницу и смотрю консоль, то мне выдает ошибку:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a
> function

ругаясь на строку

```
$("#avatar").live("change", function()
```

В чем может быть проблема? Исходный код страницы нужен? Или подскажете, что залогировать в console.log для проверки?

Comment: live — сто лет как deprecated, используйте `on`

Comment: Только что ответили про это на другом форуме. Почти идеально,но только $_POST пустой приходит при этом раскладе. Что посоветуете?

Comment: Забыл, что FILES надо проверять. Большое спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<form id="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php">
<input type="file" name="avatar" id="avatar" />
</form>
```

и

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Загружаем файл
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#avatar').on('change', function() { 
            console.log($);
            $("#preAva").html(''); // чистим preview
            $("#preAva").html('<img src="images/load.gif" height="32" />'); //показываем картинку загрузки  
            $("#formAvaUpload").ajaxForm({
                target: '#preAva'
            }).submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```